# Batch program, runs a program, opens a file, new version opens a main directory to open sub directory file

Tags: batch-file, directory

im having a little issue, I currently made a simple batch script to open this program and a specific file so that users dont have to go into the directory and open it that way, they only enter the file folder name and file name and it opens that specific file straight away, however I need it so that the user enters just the file name, I will show the simple working version which you have to type in the folder name aswell. I will also show the version I am trying to get to work without having to type the folder name, however the if statement is not working as it always runs both parts of it.

```
@echo off
set /p id2=Enter folder name for the label.
echo %id2%
set /p id=Enter Label Code, please use this format  E.G. AA-01:
echo %id%
Start ""  "C:\Program Files (x86)\EuroPlus\NiceLabel   6\bin\NicePrint.exe" "J:\MYFOLDER\%id2%\%id%.lbl"
```

^ This is the working version however it is tedious as you have to type the folder name.

```
@echo off
set STARTDIR="J:\MYFOLDER"
set /p id=Enter Label Code, please use this format  E.G. AA-01:
echo %id%
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /s /b "J:\MYFOLDER"') do echo %%a

if exist %id% in ('dir /s /b "J:\MYFOLDER"') (
echo File found, starting NicePrint.
/! set current folder where file was found
The file path is %~dp1
Start "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\EuroPlus\NiceLabel 6\bin\NicePrint.exe" "J:\MYFOLDER\%~dp1\%id%"
) else exit
pause
```

Problems with the second part: If statement always prints file found starting nice print even if user input doesnt match a file and launches the program, further more, I need the directory of that file from this so that I can then set the program to launch that file after it starts as you can see I have attempted but I am still a novice to things like this as I am not too good at programming/scripting etc.

Thank you for help in advance.

Comment: try `for /f %%a in ('dir /s /b J:\MYFOLDER\AA-01') do @echo %%a.lbl`. And don't try to guess syntax, use the [documentation](https://ss64.com/nt/)

Comment: Thank you it seems to be way better than what I had (obviously haha) I'll try to get it working thank you for your comment :)

Comment: Sorry to bother, it finds the correct directory and the file now, but i am unsure as to how I can use that to launch the file, I currently have:
Start "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\EuroPlus\NiceLabel 6\bin\NicePrint.exe" "J:\LABELS\%id%"

As you can I need to have the specific folder directory the file was found in to go inbetween the MYFOLDER and the %id% that came from the user, for example
    "J:\LABELS\FOLDERWASFOUNDIN\%id%"

Comment: What the hell is `if exist %id% in (...)`? did you mean `if exist "J:\MYFOLDER\%id%"` instead?

Comment: yeah im new to batch and was never any good with Java or just programming in general, so im trying to learn. Currently my problem is that I cant get it to open the file after it opens the program, it finds the file and the folder but I dont know how to get it to open the file it found as I need to link the directory which is displayed when the file is found but I have no clue how to now link that after the start program so that it opens it.

Comment: `for /f %%a in ('dir /s /b J:\MYFOLDER\AA-01') do Start "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\EuroPlus\NiceLabel 6\bin\NicePrint.exe" "%%a"` ?